# approximation for nth prime number

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers

Is it true that $n(\ln n+\ln \ln n-1+ \frac{\ln\ln n-2}{\ln n} + \frac{-\ln^2 \ln n+6\ln \ln n -11.5}{2 \ln^2 n}) \leq p_n \leq n(\ln n+\ln \ln n-1+ \frac{\ln\ln n-2}{\ln n} + \frac{-\ln^2 \ln n+6\ln \ln n -10.5}{2 \ln^2 n})$

? also is there a ref, is this inequality known ?

Comment: Why do you think this is true?

Comment: @saulspatz in Wikipedia it says that $p_n \approx n(\ln n+\ln \ln n-1+ \frac{\ln\ln n-2}{\ln n} + \frac{-\ln^2 \ln n+6\ln \ln n -11}{2 \ln^2 n})$ so the above inequalities seems to be true, but i searched a lot and did not see and paper concerning this inequalities

Comment: You should put this information as context in the body of your question.

Comment: Such inequalities were obtained by [Pierre Dusart](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.0442).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unconditionally the sharpest known bounds are (Due to Peierre Dusart) as follows:

For $n \ge 3$
$$
p_n \ge n\ln n + n\ln\ln n - n + \frac{n\ln\ln n - 2.1n}{\ln n} 
$$
and for $n \ge 688383$
$$
p_n \le n\ln n + n\ln\ln n - n + \frac{n\ln\ln n - 2n}{\ln n}.
$$

All such explicit upper and lower bounds will however eventually converge to the asymptotic expansion of the $n$-th prime which was derieved by Cipolla (1902).

Ref: Theorem 2.1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.1667.pdf

Comment: Axler (2014), Büthe (2014, 2015, 2017) give tighter bounds.  Of course building on Dusart's great work in 1999 and 2010.  [Also, no one of the formulas gives the tightest bounds for all ranges].

Comment: Not true. The absolute best work on this subject today is [Christian Axler's dissertation.](https://www.emis.de/journals/JIS/VOL22/Axler/axler17.pdf)

Comment: @vitaly-t A fair point in the hind sight. Answers to questions like these will have to be updated whenever the numerical bounds are improved with time